# How to show data from API in flutter using get method with bearer token

Tags: flutter, postman, bearer-token, getmethod

I have succeed to show my token when I have logged in, this token is to access the product page after login. The problem is my product page can only show data with token that I have but I don't know how to save my token and use it to show my the product data. I use Postman for my API and laravel.

My product code is only like this:

product.dart

```
class pageSuccess extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<pageSuccess> createState() => _pageSuccessState();
}

class _pageSuccessState extends State<pageSuccess> {
  var data;
  //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  //String token = sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.TOKEN)!;
  Future<void> getUserApi() async {
    final response =
        await http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/produk'),
          headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8',
            //'Authorization' : 'Bearer $token',
          },
        );
        
        
    var encodeFirst = json.encode(response.body.toString());
    data = jsonDecode(encodeFirst.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(data);
      print('product success');
    } else {
      print('product failed');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Api Course'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: FutureBuilder(
              future: getUserApi(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Text('Loading');
                } else {
                  return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: data.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Card(
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ReusbaleRow(
                                title: 'kode',
                                value: data[index]['kode'].toString(),
                              ),
                              ReusbaleRow(
                                title: 'nama',
                                value: data[index]['nama'].toString(),
                              ),
                              ReusbaleRow(
                                title: 'keterangan',
                                value: data[index]['keterangan'].toString(),
                              ),
                              ReusbaleRow(
                                title: 'harga',
                                value: data[index]['harga'].toString(),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      });
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How do I usually do it (many people do it in many way)?**
I'm getting the token when user login. So, I'm storing the token in a `shared-preferences` var.

I've created this method in constants file to access from everywhere. It's your choice where you put it.

```
Map<String, String> headersWithToken = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer $myToken'
};

String? myToken; // I'm changing this value when user success to login

class CurrentUserData {
  saveUserData(String userToken) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    preferences.setString('currentUserToken', userToken);
  }
}
```

This is login method

```
if (response.statusCode == 201) {  //login success status code 201
  //print(data['success']);

  var returnMsg = data['message'];
  var userToken = data['token'],

  setState(() {
    myToken = userToken; //I've var
  });

  toastMsg(returnMsg);

  CurrentUserData().saveUserData(userToken); //this method i'm accessing from constant file

  Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const DashboardPage()), (route) => false);
}
```

Now you can access this myToken value from everywhere.

```
http.get(Url.perse(url), headers: headersWithToken)
```

or directly

```
var res = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(userDashboardUrl),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $myToken'
    },
  );
```

Comment: can you tell me where i must put all of the code? because i still dont understand

Comment: If you want my one. So make a file yourchooce.dart and put the first snippet(my answer's) of the code there and call/import it to everywhere you want.

Comment: okay so the first code is for new dart file, and then how where i must put login method? because i have the login.dart already

Comment: Just update your login method with this if statement(Most of the time we check status code of the api response). Don't forget to update your var/key etc.

Please do some research and many videos/blogs available in online.

Comment: i cannot use setState and toastMsg in my if statement, they are all red line

Comment: join here if possible https://meet.google.com/ogi-taum-xem

Comment: lets go use gmeet